# Selenium - Protractor - Json report

Tags: json, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to publish cucumber reports as results through Jenkins. 
I am using Selenium + Protractor to run my tests. This produces a Json file which when read through Jenkins "publish cucumber reports as results" utility, gives the following error:

> org.apache.velocity.exception.MethodInvocationException: Invocation of
>   method 'getFileName' in  class net.masterthought.cucumber.json.Feature
>   threw exception java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   templates/pages/featureOverview.vm[line 360, column 73]

Following is the snapshot of my Json file:

```
[
  {
    "description": "1: As a user I want to make sure that the log in button available in the page loaded.",
    "assertions": [
      {
        "passed": true
      },
      {
        "passed": true
      }
    ],
    "duration": 3094516706
  },
  {
    "description": "2: As a user with correct username and incorrect password, user should be shown error message.",
    "assertions": [
      {
        "passed": true
      },
      {
        "passed": true
      }
    ],
    "duration": 694093948
  },
  {
    "description": "3: As a user with incorrect username and correct password, user should be shown error message.",
    "assertions": [
      {
        "passed": true
      },
      {
        "passed": true
      },
      {
        "passed": true
      }
    ],
    "duration": 1577337485
  },
  {
    "description": "4: As a user I want to sign in to the Space Planner Platform directly from a URL using my Self Serve Login details.",
    "assertions": [
      {
        "passed": true
      },
      {
        "passed": true
      },
      {
        "passed": true
      }
    ],
    "duration": 2090233702
  }
]
```